# Moving my existing flutter project to bloc architechture

Tags: flutter, architecture, bloc

The project assigned to me is a huge project with multiple screens and widgets.
This project does not follow any kind of architecture. We are facing many issues related to state management and decided to move the project to bloc.
Now my question is what could be the best approach to move this existing project, can we do it in module wise or do we need to start from scratch. Is there any guideline exist to shift existing projects to bloc.
I understand it completely depends on the project and requirements but still, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think doing it module by module would be best because there is a pattern to writing BLoC code.

Comment: That means I should modify modules in existing project only?

Comment: Please I don't understand, are there multiple projects that your own project depends on that have the same issue, because it seems I didn't fully understand what you meant

Comment: Single but huge one... Started with small parts/modules. thanks anyway!

Comment: For me the "project does not follow any kind of architecture" cries like: start from scratch and only port small working parts. I can highly recommend checking out [this architecture explained here](https://verygood.ventures/blog/very-good-flutter-architecture) - which is basically designed by the creators of bloc.